# function that returns the k-th value in binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need to write a function that returns the k-ith value in his size in binary search tree

e.g if this is the binary search tree:

```
                                  50
                                 /  \
                               46    58
                              / \    / \
                            32  48  53  67
```

then if k=3 so the function should return 48

because 48 is in the third place in his size.

32,46,48,50,53,58,67.

My idea is to use inorder somehow but I'm stuck a lot of hours, I don't think that it should be hard, I need a pseudo code or a better code then mine please.

here is what I did in JAVA eclipse:

```
private static void k_val_inorder(TreeItem x,int k)
{       
    if (x != null&&k!=0)
    {
        k_val_inorder(x.getLeft(),k--);
        System.out.print(x.getKey()+" ");
        k_val_inorder(x.getRight(),k--);        
    }   

}
```

any ideas please?

Comment: Convert the tree to infix array and get the value at k-th position of that array.

Comment: Gave a solution. Please check and confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given TreeNode class to implement a binary tree:

```
public class TreeNode {
    int data;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    TreeNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Infix traversal for a given binary tree:

```
public void inFix(TreeNode root, List<Integer> inFixRep) {
    if (root != null) {
        inFix(root.left, inFixRep);
        inFixRep.add(root.data);
        inFix(root.right, inFixRep);
    }
}
```

The above method populates a `List<Integer>`. This list contains the infix representation of the given binary tree. To get the k-th node, just get the (k-1)th element of the list like `inFixRep.get(k-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder works but is linear, this can be achieved in log(n) time. If you keep track of the number of nodes contained in the subtree of the node, then you can arrange a function to run in logarithmic time. In python, it looks like that:

```
def select(node, k):
    if node == null:
        return null
    t = node.left == null ? 0 : node.count
    if t > k:
        return select(node.left, k)
    if t < k:
        return select(node.right, k-t-1)
    return node.data
```

EDIT:

It works in log(n) time for balanced tree, but with standard BST the worst-case time is still linear. Still, it is faster than inorder in the average case.

Comment: This only works in `log(n)` time for **balanced** trees.